# xml getting the last row value while transforming to xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a scenario where I want the  value of the last row of the < function > tag in the target html files  ( passstatus,failstatus,errorstatus ) etc. I have tried like this using the last() method to get that, but  its not working for me , Please help me resolve the issue.Thanks for help.

This is my xml file

```
<TestSuite>
    <TestCase>
        <name>checkLoginPage</name>
        <function>
            <method>test</method>
            <status>ERROR</status>
            <reason>Traceback (most recent call last):</reason>
            <passstatus>0</passstatus>
            <failstatus>0</failstatus>
            <errorstatus>1</errorstatus>
            <method>test1</method>
            <status>FAIL</status>
            <reason>Traceback (most recent call last):</reason>
            <passstatus>0</passstatus>
            <failstatus>1</failstatus>
            <errorstatus>1</errorstatus>
        </function>
    </TestCase>
</TestSuite>
```

This is my xslt file

```
<table border="1" id="result_table">
    <tr bgcolor="#777">
        <th align="left">TestFile/TestCase</th>
        <th align="left">Pass</th>
        <th align="left">Fail</th>
        <th align="left">Error</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/function">
        <xsl:if test="status='FAIL'">
            <tr bgcolor="#6c6">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>.
                    <xsl:value-of select="method"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/*[last()]/passstatus"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="failstatus"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="errorstatus"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
```

This is the target file I expect from the transformation ,

```
<html xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
   <head>
      <style>
  td {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    padding: 2px;

}


</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border="1" id="result_table">
         <tr bgcolor="#777">
            <th align="left">TestFile/TestCase</th>
            <th align="left">Pass</th>
            <th align="left">Fail</th>
            <th align="left">Error</th>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#6c6">
            <td>checkLoginPage.test2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
         </tr>

      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your XML sample complete? You only have one `function` element under the `TestCase`. Should there be multiple ones? (One for each method, perhaps?) I also notice your XSLT is checking for `status='PASS'`, but your XML sample only has ERROR and FAIL. It might help if you showed the output you expect in this case. Thanks.

Comment: I have function one for each testcase, I have edited the status, I have posted part of the xslt file in there.  that passstatus,failstatus variable inside the function , held the current pass,fail count , lets say inside the function i have 3 method tag , and 2 passed and 1 failed then passtatus is 2 and failedstatus is 1 . Like wise i want the last value that is 2,1 in my code.

Comment: Do you actually need to use `sum` here? For example, `<xsl:value-of select="sum(passstatus)"/>`.

Comment: @Tim , Not sum. I can able to get the correct value in the last tag inside the function, But my problem is how to do i make only that last stats value as the row value in the transformed html

Comment: If you wanted the last stats value, you would do `<xsl:value-of select="passstatus[last()]" />`

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I am getting that last value but 3 times , one for error,failure,pass, Is there any way to get that only once, for 1 loop ? I can able to achieve with the lastrow tag , if it is set , print only that , is there any other simple way to do that ? because while construting that xml , i wont be able to identify which one is lastrow , later i need to read it and modify the value again , which will be hectic.

Comment: I suppose you do not have the option to emit better-structured XML in the first place?  The current structure seems to rely on document order to associate related `<method>`, `<status>`, *etc*. elements together, but it would be much better to associate them by wrapping them in a containing element.

Comment: @John , can you show me some sample for it ? XML structure I have liberty to change.

Comment: Anyway, you keep saying the "last row", but the form of your desired output makes me think that what you actually want is the `<passstatus>` that goes with the current `<method>`.

Comment: No, Lets say I have 8 methods inside the function tag,  I want the 8th method passstatus which eventually is my last row in the function tag

Comment: @SaranyaSridharan, if you can change the XML, then you might do `<function><method>oneMethod</method>...<passstatus>...</passstatus>...</function><function><method>anotherMethod</method>...</function>'.

Comment: Ok @John . I will do that. What about that problem I told before to Tim , I am getting 3 rows in the html , each for 1 method , I want only one row for each testcase Tag. How do i acheive that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have accepted my suggestion in comments to change the XML format, let's consider a restructured XML input of this form:

```
<TestSuite>
  <TestCase>
    <name>checkLoginPage</name>
    <function>
      <method>test</method>
      <status>ERROR</status>
      <reason>Traceback (most recent call last):</reason>
      <passstatus>0</passstatus>
      <failstatus>0</failstatus>
      <errorstatus>1</errorstatus>
    </function>
    <function>
      <method>test1</method>
      <status>FAIL</status>
      <reason>Traceback (most recent call last):</reason>
      <passstatus>0</passstatus>
      <failstatus>1</failstatus>
      <errorstatus>1</errorstatus>
    </function>
  </TestCase>
</TestSuite>
```

(I'd actually consider a different element name than "function" there, but the above is what was discussed in comments.)

The question, then, becomes how to select only the last (in document order) `<function>` element in each `<TestCase>` for transformation, but now that's simple: you can use a predicate involving the `last()` function, just as you initially tried to do.  For example,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1" id="result_table">
      <tr bgcolor="#777">
        <th align="left">TestFile/TestCase</th>
        <th align="left">Pass</th>
        <th align="left">Fail</th>
        <th align="left">Error</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- here's the key XPath expression: -->
      <xsl:for-each select="/TestSuite/TestCase/function[last()]">
        <xsl:if test="status='FAIL'">
      <tr bgcolor="#6c6">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::TestCase/name"/>.<xsl:value-of select="method"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="passstatus"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="failstatus"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="errorstatus"/></td>
      </tr>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the restructured input (as presented in this answer) that produces

```
<table border="1" id="result_table">
  <tr bgcolor="#777">
    <th align="left">TestFile/TestCase</th>
    <th align="left">Pass</th>
    <th align="left">Fail</th>
    <th align="left">Error</th>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#6c6">
    <td>checkLoginPage.test1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

, which seems to be the form you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @John. It works perfectly. I will change that function tag, for me also it was looking odd. :)